# WSO2 Identity Server: Forming OIDC Endpoint URLs behind a load balancer

Tags: wso2, catalina, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity Server 5.7.0. I am having an issue forming the OAuth2 and OIDC Endpoint URLs. When I run the IS locally, I use a catalina-server.xml configuration where there is an HTTPS connector on port 9443. In this situation, the OIDC Endpoint URLs are formed with 9443 as the ${carbon.management.port} and the redirection to these URLs functions as expected. When I run the IS behind a load balancer, however, I only open an HTTP connector in catalina-server.xml to communicate with the load balancer. Traffic hits the load balancer over HTTPS and it appears that with ${carbon.protocol} set to "https" and without an HTTPS connector, the ${carbon.management.port} is set to "-1", which is not a valid port. 
My question is whether there is a way to manually set the ${carbon.management.port} variable, or, if not, whether there is a way to configure the catalina-server.xml with only an HTTP connector to have ${carbon.management.port} set to 443 (so that redirects properly hit the port the LB is open on and not the port the server communicates with the LB on). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [1] if proxy port can resolve your issue. Basically you can listen to https traffic from 443 and route to 9443. For HTTP traffic 80 to 9763.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Setting+Up+Deployment+Pattern+1#SettingUpDeploymentPattern1-Changinghostnamesandports

Comment: Thank you for responding, but it didn't seem to work with a proxy port of 443 on the connector listening over HTTP.

Comment: check this too https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Configuring+TLS+Termination#ConfiguringTLSTermination-Step1:ConfiguringtheloadbalancerwithTLStermination